# SQLite3 (py) - Change cell variable to null where date less than now but in DD/MM/YYYY format

Tags: python, date, sqlite

### How to change date format in SQLite3 querying?

I have looked at similar problems however I cannot get them working, or find any in python to get the correct syntax, may have translated wrong.

---

In my table I have the booking date set as UK date and I want to set another variable to null when the date has passed.

I tried to use:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE AthensiPads SET UserName = null WHERE BookedDate < date('now')")
```

But this doesn't work; replaces every row with null as the date format is wrong so it compares `03/05/2017` (date in table) with `2017-05-03` so 2017 is always higher than 22 so it sets it to null. Worked this out by replacing `null` with `date('now')`.

So I need to put the `2017-05-03` into `03/05/2017` format to compare properly, how would I do this, give examples or something please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite has no date parsing functions; you'd have to use the [`substr()` function](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) to extract the right 'numbers' and pass the resulting reconstructed string to the [`date()` function](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```sql
UPDATE AthensiPads SET UserName = null
WHERE date(
    substr(BookedDate, 7, 4) || '-' ||
    substr(BookedDate, 4, 2) || '-' ||
    substr(BookedDate, 1, 2)
) < date('now')
```

Demo:

```
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn.execute('CREATE TABLE AthensiPads(UserName, BookedDate)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10cdad500>
>>> with conn:
...     cursor = conn.cursor()
...     cursor.executemany('''
...         INSERT INTO AthensiPads VALUES(?, ?)
...     ''', (
...         ('foo', '03/05/2017'),
...         ('bar', '01/12/2015'),
...     ))
...
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10cdad570>
>>> with conn:
...     cursor = conn.cursor()
...     cursor.execute('''
...         UPDATE AthensiPads SET UserName = null
...         WHERE date(
...             substr(BookedDate, 7, 4) || '-' ||
...             substr(BookedDate, 4, 2) || '-' ||
...             substr(BookedDate, 1, 2)
...         ) < date('now')
...     ''')
...
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10cdad490>
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> for row in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM AthensiPads'):
...     print(row)
...
('foo', '03/05/2017')
(None, '01/12/2015')
```

Comment: Thank-you very much! Very helpful!